# How to get a return from Deferred Object JQuery

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a function to load events (for a calendar) which should return data to be parsed by Mustache.
The problem i got is that I can't find a way to return processed data inside request.done()

Here's my function

```
this.load = function() {
    var events = createArray(7, { content: [] });
    var data = {
        from: Math.floor(this.week[0].valueOf() / 1000),
        to: Math.floor(this.week[6].valueOf() / 1000)
    };
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: this.loadPath,
        data: data,
        type: 'POST'
    });

    request.done(function(response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        response.forEach(function(event) {
            event.date = new Date(event.date);
            var thisEvent = {
                id: event.id,
                time: event.date.format('HH:MM'),
                title: event.title,
                description: event.description,
                color: event.color,
                link: event.link
            };

            // Why is thisEvent added to each events[].content and not just for events[day].content?
            events[event.date.getRealDay()].content.push(thisEvent);
        });
    });

    // return statement has to be executed only when request.done() has finished
    // or find a way to return directly from request.done()
    return { events: events };
};
```

Thank you for your help

EDIT: Solution found

```
this.load = function() {
    var data = {
        from: Math.floor(this.week[0].valueOf() / 1000),
        to: Math.floor(this.week[6].valueOf() / 1000)
    };
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: this.loadPath,
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        context: this
    });
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    request.done(function(response) {
        var events = createArray(7, { content: [] });
        response = JSON.parse(response);

        response.forEach(function(event) {
            event.date = new Date(event.date);
            var thisEvent = { // Why does the
                id: event.id,
                time: event.date.format('HH:MM'),
                title: event.title,
                description: event.description,
                color: event.color,
                link: event.link
            };
            events[event.date.getRealDay()].content.push(thisEvent); // Why is thisEvent added to each events[].content and not just for events[day].content?
        });
        deferred.resolveWith(this, events);
    });
    request.fail(deferred.reject);

    return deferred.promise();
};
```

From another function I can call :

```
this.load().done(function(events) {
    this.events = events;
    this.render();
});
```

Comment: Your `load` function will either need to accept a callback to execute in the `.done` function or return a promise that gets resolved in the `.done` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your doing it wrong.

Your function should either :

- Perform a sync ajax - that's a bad idea in 99% of the issues.
- Return a promise from the function and the callback will happen when the deferred object gets resolved(or rejected).

Something like this:

function:

```
 this.load = function() {
    var events = createArray(7, { content: [] });
    var data = {
        from: Math.floor(this.week[0].valueOf() / 1000),
        to: Math.floor(this.week[6].valueOf() / 1000)
    };
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: this.loadPath,
        data: data,
        type: 'POST'
    });

    return request;
};
```

call:

```
this.load().done(done(function(response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        response.forEach(function(event) {
            event.date = new Date(event.date);
            var thisEvent = { // Why does the
                id: event.id,
                time: event.date.format('HH:MM'),
                title: event.title,
                description: event.description,
                color: event.color,
                link: event.link
            };

            // Why is thisEvent added to each events[].content and not just for events[day].content?
            events[event.date.getRealDay()].content.push(thisEvent);

           // Do your stuff in the correct scope.
        });
    });
```

Or, keep it the way you have:

```
this.load = function() {
    var events = createArray(7, { content: [] });
    var data = {
        from: Math.floor(this.week[0].valueOf() / 1000),
        to: Math.floor(this.week[6].valueOf() / 1000)
    };
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: this.loadPath,
        data: data,
        type: 'POST'
    });

    request.done(function(response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        response.forEach(function(event) {
            event.date = new Date(event.date);
            var thisEvent = { // Why does the
                id: event.id,
                time: event.date.format('HH:MM'),
                title: event.title,
                description: event.description,
                color: event.color,
                link: event.link
            };

            // Why is thisEvent added to each events[].content and not just for events[day].content?
            events[event.date.getRealDay()].content.push(thisEvent);
        });
    });

   return request;
};
```

Call:

```
this.load.done(function(){alert('im done, do your stuff here')});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with promises, could you show me an example in this case?

Comment: I did..your function returns the request var which is a promise.
The done function will run as soon as the request will receive a response.

Comment: @Amiros: Though you have the right concept, I don't agree with your implementation. the `.done` logic should remain in `.load` (otherwise you're re-implementing it where ever you call load). You can, however, create a new promise and return that once the ajax has completed (or failed).

Comment: @BradChristie - that is an option as well..I just wanted to show that you return a promise that you can "chain" callbacks on..

Answer (score 1):

The `.ajax` call makes this asynchronous. You can't return anything from the ajax complete callback back through the same `.load` method. If you want to do additional handling, you're better off returning the deferred object and letting your additional code bind to `.done` as well.

---

For example:

```
this.load = function() {
    var data = {
        from: Math.floor(this.week[0].valueOf() / 1000),
        to: Math.floor(this.week[6].valueOf() / 1000)
    };
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: this.loadPath,
        data: data,
        type: 'POST'
    });

    // create a deferred object we can return
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    request.done(function(response) {
        // move events code down here
        var events = createArray(7, { content: [] });
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        response.forEach(function(event) {
            event.date = new Date(event.date);
            var thisEvent = { // Why does the
                id: event.id,
                time: event.date.format('HH:MM'),
                title: event.title,
                description: event.description,
                color: event.color,
                link: event.link
            };
            events[event.date.getRealDay()].content.push(thisEvent);
        });
        deferred.resolve(events);
    }).fail(deferred.reject); // on failure our deferred object should fail too.

    // return the deferred object.
    return deferred.promise();
};
```

Then you would use it like an ajax call:

```
this.load().done(function(events){
  // now events is populated
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but what if i want to store events in another variable outside of the function called by `.done()`?

Comment: You can change the scope of `events`, but keep in mind it's not actually populated until the `.done` callback returns. So, if you do go to read it, be sure to test it first.

Comment: Ok I edited my first post with the solution i found. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a callback when you're done:

```
this.load = function(cb) {
//...
    request.done(function(response) {
       // do your stuff with the events etc.
        cb(events);
    }
};
```

Then call it like

```
load(function(events){
    // events manipulated and ready to use
});
```

Or create a new promise and resolve it:

```
this.load = function() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    //...
    request.done(function(response) {
       // do your stuff with the events etc.
       dfd.resolve(events);

    }).fail(dfd.reject); // reject on error

    return dfd.promise();
};
```

Call it in a similar way:

```
load.done(function(events){
    // handle events
}).fail(function(){
   // handle errors
});
```